# How to assign values to indexed arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to get

```
[1,2
 4,5
 7,8]
```

ndarray[:][0:2]

it get

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6]])
```

why!?

Comment: You are only slicing in the y-axis. The correct syntax is `ndarray[:, 0:2]`

Answer (score 0):

`ndarray[:]` returns an identical array and when you use `[0:2]`, it returns an arry with the first 2 elements, and hence `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

What you want to do is this : `ndarray[0:3,0:2]` or simpler `ndarray[:,:2]`

This will return a slice of the array slicing in 2 dimensions

Answer (score 0):

ndarray[:] gives you the whole array, and with the following [0:2] you select the first two element of it, which is [1,2,3] and [4,5,6].

You need to slice (as DavidG already suggested) in the first bracket for all desired dimensions:

ndarray[:,0:2]

P.S.: Please change your title to something, that relates closer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

print(a[:])
```

Output: same as a, as you are selecting all of the rows:

> [[1 2 3]  [4 5 6]  [7 8 9]]

Then indexing on that will apply the index on the result, all of the rows (i.e. `a[:][0:2]` is equivalent to `a[0:2]` - selecting the first two rows)

To select the first two columns:

```
print(a[:, 0:2])
```

Output (as expected):

> [[1 2]  [4 5]  [7 8]]

I would recommend going through Numpy's indexing documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html